# What does the type a -> b Bool mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I know that type:

```
a -> Bool
```

is a function that takes as input something of type a and outputs a boolean.

What does type:

```
a -> b Bool
```

mean?

Comment: Is that the entire type? Or is there a context like `(Foldable b) => a -> b Bool`?

Comment: I didn't get any more context about the type, I'm seeing a -> b Bool for the first time through a hugs Type error:

*** Does not match : a -> b Bool

Comment: Could you add the code that results in that error?

Comment: Since you indicate that you're an absolute beginner: you're either just seeing a syntax error, or you're waaay out of your depth. The first step towards understanding this would be to learn about `Maybe`.

Comment: e.g. `g x = pure True` has a type `Applicative f => t -> f Bool`.

Comment: Is there a particular bit of code that this is from? If so, it would help us to answer if you provide that part as well.

Comment: Asking what a fragment of an error message means is not a good way to get help, here or anywhere else. You must post the code to avoid having the question closed as off-topic. You should also post the full text of the error message if it's less than 20 lines or so.

Comment: Also, Hugs is obsolete. I know there's still a teacher using it for his classes, but everyone else has been using GHCi for the last ten-plus years. You probably should do the same.

Answer (score 6):

In `b Bool`, `b` stands for a parametrized type that takes one type parameter (in Haskell parlance, `b` is a type constructor of kind `* -> *`), such as `Maybe`, `IO` or `[]`.

So a function of type `a -> b Bool` could for example take an `Int` and produce a `Maybe Bool`, `IO Bool`, `[Bool]` etc.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson In the context of a type error messages, that does not apply though. When the compiler says that it expects the type `a -> b Bool` that does not mean that the function really needs to have that exact type - you can give it a function `Int -> Maybe Bool` and it will be satisfied.

Comment: Quite true, how sloppy of me.

Comment: @sepp2k ... unless `b` is rigid

Answer (score 3):

It might be clearer if you write it out with explicit quantification and kind annotations. `a -> b Bool` means...

```
forall (a :: *) (b :: * -> *). a -> b Bool
```

`b` is therefore a *type constructor* taking a single type argument. Examples of single-argument type constructors abound: `Maybe`, `[]`, `IO` are all examples of things which you could use to instantiate `b`.

A function `f :: a -> b Bool` takes an argument of any type `a`; its return value is the type constructor of your choice with its parameter filled in as `Bool`.

Parametricity tells us that there aren't any (non-⊥) terms with such a type.

Comment: I'm an absolute beginner, this answer has a lot of things I don't understand. I don't completely understand what Maybe means, and I also don't understand what the symbol ⊥ here indicates.

Comment: The symbol ⊥ is called "bottom", and it basically means "pathological terms" such as those which throw errors or loop for ever. My favourite Haskell beginners' book is _Learn You A Haskell For Great Good_, which you can [read online for free](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters). Good luck learning this beautiful language!

Answer (score 3):

In this case `b` is a higher kinded type, i.e. a function from types to types. Sounds scary? Fear not! A higher kinded type is something like the list type. `([])` on it's own is not a type, but it still takes an argument to become one, so `([]) Int = [Int]` is a type.

Kinds are like the types of types and the kind of a fully applied type is `*`. The kind of list on the other hand is `* -> *`. So it takes a type `*` (e.g. `Int`) and returns a type (e.g. `[Int]`). Other examples would be `Maybe`, `IO` or the function type `(->)` which has kind `* -> * -> *` because it still takes to types, an argument type and a result type (e.g. `(->) Int Bool = Int -> Bool`).

The function that you have given is actually impossible to implement, just like a function of type `a -> b`. However a function we could implement is the following:

```
pureEq :: (Eq a, Applicative b) => a -> a -> b Bool
pureEq x y = pure (x == y)
```